# How to translate SQL UPDATE query which uses inner join into PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, sql-update, azure-databricks

I have two MS Access SQL queries which I want to convert into PySpark. The queries look like this (we have two tables Employee and Department):

```sql
UPDATE EMPLOYEE INNER JOIN [DEPARTMENT] ON
EMPLOYEE.STATEPROVINCE = [DEPARTMENT].[STATE_LEVEL] 
SET EMPLOYEE.STATEPROVINCE = [DEPARTMENT]![STATE_ABBREVIATION];
```

```sql
UPDATE EMPLOYEE INNER JOIN [DEPARTMENT] ON
EMPLOYEE.STATEPROVINCE = [DEPARTMENT].[STATE_LEVEL] 
SET EMPLOYEE.MARKET = [DEPARTMENT]![MARKET];
```

Comment: what do you want to update ? A dataframe is just the result of a select, so you can "update" your dataframe with a simple join statement. If you want to update a table stored somewhere, it depends on the target techno.

Comment: i have loaded this sql data into my datalake first and then loading it into dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test dataframes:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_emp = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'a'), (2, 'bb')], ['EMPLOYEE', 'STATEPROVINCE'])
df_emp.show()
# +--------+-------------+
# |EMPLOYEE|STATEPROVINCE|
# +--------+-------------+
# |       1|            a|
# |       2|           bb|
# +--------+-------------+

df_dept = spark.createDataFrame([('bb', 'b')], ['STATE_LEVEL', 'STATE_ABBREVIATION'])
df_dept.show()
# +-----------+------------------+
# |STATE_LEVEL|STATE_ABBREVIATION|
# +-----------+------------------+
# |         bb|                 b|
# +-----------+------------------+
```

Running your SQL query in Microsoft Access does the following:

[image]

In PySpark, you can get it like this:

```py
df = (df_emp.alias('a')
    .join(df_dept.alias('b'), df_emp.STATEPROVINCE == df_dept.STATE_LEVEL, 'left')
    .select(
        *[c for c in df_emp.columns if c != 'STATEPROVINCE'],
        F.coalesce('b.STATE_ABBREVIATION', 'a.STATEPROVINCE').alias('STATEPROVINCE')
    )
)
df.show()
# +--------+-------------+
# |EMPLOYEE|STATEPROVINCE|
# +--------+-------------+
# |       1|            a|
# |       2|            b|
# +--------+-------------+
```

First you do a left `join`. Then, `select`.

The `select` has 2 parts.

- First, you select everything from `df_emp` except for "STATEPROVINCE".
- Then, for the new "STATEPROVINCE", you select "STATE_ABBREVIATION" from `df_dept`, but in case it's null (i.e. not existent in `df_dept`), you take "STATEPROVINCE" from `df_emp`.

For your second query, you only need to change values in the `select` statement:

```py
df = (df_emp.alias('a')
    .join(df_dept.alias('b'), df_emp.STATEPROVINCE == df_dept.STATE_LEVEL, 'left')
    .select(
        *[c for c in df_emp.columns if c != 'MARKET'],
        F.coalesce('b.MARKET', 'a.MARKET').alias('MARKET')
    )
)
```

Comment: hi , i want to use inner join here right for getting my desired result or we have to use left join only

Comment: You don't need innner join. That was needed in Access only, as a way to show which rows to update. But in PySpark you don't need it, as it would cause more problems.

Comment: Please try analyzing the answer. It's not a big difference, you could have done it yourself! I've done it this time - I've updated the answer.